# Bracing Against a Charge and Reach

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, opportunity-attack, readied-action

If I were to set myself up to brace for a charge with a Longspear, do I get both my readied attack for double damage when they move into reach and my attack of opportunity for normal damage (or would it be double still because they're still charging?) for when they move through my threatened area, assuming they don't also have a reach weapon?

Comment: Interesting, for sure you would only get one AoO, no matter how many squares you threaten and your opponent crosses; but I have no idea whether you get the readied action on top or not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

The actions happen in order, first the enemy enters a square that you threaten, triggering your [readied action](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialInitiativeActions.htm) (assuming that you specified the 'charges me' (and thus enters my threatened area) as the trigger) for double damage (as this attack uses the [spear's special property](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Spear)).

SRD text for a spear (emphasis mine):

> If you **use a ready action** to set a spear against a charge, you deal
>   double damage on a successful hit against a charging character.

The next thing your opponent does is attempt to leave your threatened area, triggering an attack of opportunity as per the rules of [AoO](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/attacksOfOpportunity.htm). However, this attack will deal regular damage as this attack is not performed because of a readied action.

Key argument:

Specifying the 'use a ready action' in the spear's property line implies that it only applies to the attack that is triggered by that ready action.

Comment: Do you think this would hold with the *Steadfast Boots* (MIC)? These boots have the property than any two-handed weapon held is considered readied against a charge (even if not dealing piercing damages).

Comment: The boots would make the AoO also deal double damage. However, this is not what the OP was asking.

Comment: One thing, though: Does the spear double its damage because it **consumed a ready action**, or because it was **set against a charge**? ^_^

Comment: @BasJansen I don't think boots work the way you say. They give you free attack against any creature that charges you. And this attack is dealt as if it was an attack from ready (i.e. double damage on that particular free attack).

Comment: @annoyingimp I have to ask on what you base that. The text reads to me as if the damage is doubled when making an attack on a charging opponent (but nothing indicating a free attack).

Comment: @BasJansen I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31372/steadfast-boots-mechanics) on this topic

Comment: I thought so but at the same time that would mean my character is kinda breaking the rules of physics by being able to pull that spear back faster than that guy is already running haha. As to the boots, I'm totally jumping on that tread and adding my feedback. See what I did there? ;)